# Python: Scrapy exports raw data instead of text() only?

Tags: python, class, parsing, export, scrapy

I'm exporting from this class:

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name =  "dozen"
    allowed_domains = ["yahoo.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://finance.yahoo.com/q/is?s=SCMP+Income+Statement&annual"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        revenue = hxs.select('//td[@align="right"]')
        items = []
        for rev in revenue:
            item = DozenItem()
            item["Revenue"] = rev.xpath("./strong/text()")
            items.append(item)
        return items[:7]
```

and getting this:

```
[<HtmlXPathSelector xpath='./strong/text()' data=u'\n                            115,450\xa0\xa0\n '>]
```

But I only want the `115,450`.

If I add `.extract()` to the end of my `item["Revenue"]` line, it exports nothing.

Here is the section of html which includes what I'm trying to grab:

```
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<strong>Total Revenue</strong>
</td>
<td align="right">
<strong>115,450&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>
</td>
<td align="right">
<strong>89,594&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>
</td>
<td align="right">
<strong>81,487&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use too broad of an Xpath expression for the first selection.
Try it like this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    revenue = response.xpath('//td[@align="right"]/strong/text()')
    items = []
    for rev in revenue:
        item = DozenItem()
        item["Revenue"] = rev.re('\d*,\d*')
        items.append(item)
    return items[:3]
```

Comment: I had no idea how broad or specific to be. This was very helpful, however the export displays `,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,115,,450,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,` for each number. Do you know how I could reduce the several additional characters?

Comment: Yes, check the updated expression, I made an edit in the mantime.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing well. Can you show html please?

Normally, I use this code:

```
rev.xpath("./strong/text()").extract()[0].encode('utf8').strip()
```

Comment: What you suggested is how I've done it in the past, however now it just exports empty

Comment: It's correct. But you can try with .re('\d+') for example... I don't know the reason of the problem